# wp_remote_get adding backslashes

Tags: php, json, wp-remote-get

I am having this issue where wp_remote_get appears to be adding backslashes "\" to my string. It also adds things in like body and headers.

```
{"headers":{},
"body":" {\"page\":1,\"total_results\":44,\"total_pages\":3,\"results\": [{\"vote_count\":7398,\"id\":299536,\"video\":false,\"vote_average\":8.3,\"title\":\"Avengers: Infinity War\",\"popularity\":220.311,\"poster_path\":\"\\/7WsyChQLEftFiDOVTGkv3hFpyyt.jpg\",\"original_language\":\"en\",\"original_title\":\"Avengers: Infinity War\",\"genre_ids\":
```

If I use a curl however I get the following string. This is what I want my string to look like.

```
{"page":1,"total_results":44,"total_pages":3,"results":[{"vote_count":7398,"id":299536,"video":false,"vote_average":8.3,"title":"Avengers: Infinity War","popularity":220.311,"poster_path":"\/7WsyChQLEftFiDOVTGkv3hFpyyt.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"Avengers: Infinity War","genre_ids":
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to apply `stripslashes()` on the response body. E.g.: `$body = stripslashes( $body );`

Comment: Thanks for the help Sally, turns out it was due to something else but thank you for the help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_remote_get()` returns an array containing the response headers and the response body. When you `json_encode()` the response, which you appear to have done, then the body is going to be escaped so that it doesn't break the JSON it thinks you're trying to create. *You're* adding the slashes when you do this.

To get the body of the response you need to then use `wp_remote_retrieve_body()`. Then to turn the JSON into an array, you need to use `json_decode()`:

```
$request = wp_remote_get( $url );
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

var_dump( json_decode( $response ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Jacob, I really appreciate. Can't believe it was such a silly mistake on my part. I didn't realise it automatically did headers and the response body, I probably should have read the documentation more carefully. Anyway sorry for the rant.